# NSLayoutConstraint animation finishes instantly

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a very simple project, I want to animate the right margin on a label, however when I try it, it finishes instantly.

```
@IBAction func onDo(sender:UIButton)
{
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.testConstraint.constant = 40.0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.setNeedsLayout()

        }) { (complete:Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

The project is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a0v0906riunkww/test2222.zip?dl=0

Am I missing something obvious?

**Update #1**

It seems it's a problem with UILabels specifically, a standard UIView, or UIButton animates fine....so whats wrong with a UILabel?

**Update #2**

If I set the UILabel View Content Mode to Center, then it works fine, but it doesn't look very smooth...very strange.

Comment: Call `layoutIfNeeded()`, not `setNeedsLayout()`

Comment: I have tried that in the test project and it jumps too :-(

Comment: It's weird, there are some thoughts here http://stackoverflow.com/q/17360402/2683201

Answer (score 0):

I may be off the mark here, but it looks to me as though your animation routine just does `setNeedslayout`, which will cause the screen to redraw instantly. You need to change some animatable parameter of the UIView in order to see something move. Like `self.view.frame`, perhaps. The animatable properties of UIView are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` in animation closure with `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

```
@IBAction func onDo(sender:UIButton) {
    self.testConstraint.constant = 40.0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (complete:Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```