# UILabel does not animate inside UIView, autolayouts used

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout

I have a very simple application. It contains a red view and a green label inside it. There is also a button that runs animation. I animate the red view by changing its width constraint constant's value.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    self.widthConstraint.constant = width;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

The red view animates as expected, but the green label inside changes its width instantly. I played with different animation flags, tried several tips from SO but did not bring it work.

Please find [the sources here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb5fv7rp1qw7idf/testAutolatyoutAnimation.zip?dl=0).

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like I've found the root of the problem. Constraints are not a trouble, `UILabel` is.

If you replace `UILabel` in my project with simple `UIView` it will animate smoothly as expected. It's a question of `UILabel` content animation. You can reach correct animation behaviour set `label.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter` but it looks ugly.

The best way to solve this problem - not try to change size of `UILabel` during animation. Try to invent some other behaviour. In my case I change `UILabel`'s alpha to 0 and x position to greater then container view's width.

Please find more details about `UILabel` animating [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298764/animating-uilabel-size-decrease/7923430#7923430).

Answer (score 0):

I have took a look at your project. I have not that much experience with setting constraints from editor but I would highly recommend you in case of troubles try to do it in code. Personally I would animate constraint on width of this red view and set constraints on the label's margins using visual format it will be something like: `@"H:|[label]|"` and add this this constraint to red view. That should solve the problem.