# UILabel size change doesn't animate with auto layout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have an dynamic-width `UILabel` (colored lime-green for visibility) which has a fixed leading and trailing constraint to its neighbours (the green and red views). I want this table to adapt its width when one of its neighbours is moved (the rounded red/green view). However, I am having an issue with the animation of this change since the width of my label "jumps" to its new value without animating. For my right-aligned label this means that the text itself jumps too.

[image]

I am animating the movement of the red/green view like this:

```
- (void)show {
    self.edgeConstraint.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)hide {
    self.edgeConstraint.constant = -100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Call `layoutIfNeeded` before setting the constraints.. then call `layoutIfNeeded` inside the animation block (you are already doing this one). See if that works.

Comment: This gif is what you want or the problem ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `UILabel` content mode. You see a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711321/5442445). Because you are shortening the label where the text is drawn, the label does a drawing pass, but it uses the final frame of the animation block for the update. The easiest way create a smooth animation is to use a `greaterThanOrEqualTo` leading constraint and set the `textAlignment` to `.natural`.

When I do that I get the result on top as apposed to setting `textAlignment` `.right` on bottom.

[image: Screencast]

Source code for demo:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var otherConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    lazy private var sideView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.constraint = view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        self.constraint?.isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return view
    }()

    lazy private var secondSideView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 44.0).isActive = true
        self.otherConstraint = view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        self.otherConstraint?.isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return view
    }()

    lazy private var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Label"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.sideView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        return label
    }()

    lazy private var secondLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.text = "Label"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 44.0).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.sideView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.secondSideView.isHidden = false
        self.secondLabel.isHidden = false
        self.sideView.isHidden = false
        self.label.isHidden = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.perform(#selector(self.showSideView), with: nil, afterDelay: 5.0)
    }

    @objc private func showSideView() {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
            self.otherConstraint?.constant = -100
            self.constraint?.constant = -100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: You were absolutely right that the issue is with the text redrawing. As soon as I started reading your answer I remembered that I had this issue once before where I ended up using a scale transform (in that case the UILabel was being shrunk in both width and height). Your suggestion with using a "greater then or equal to" leading/trailing constraint did the trick perfectly. Thanks!